# IDA special fields in stack window

Tags: ida

When you open the stack window in IDA with `Ctrl-K` there is a comment at the top saying:

; Two special fields " r" and " s" represent return address and saved registers.

When I made some mistake and undefined these fields, then how can I recreate them? Defining data creates just a normal variable type. Or can those not be set, so I have to live with the data types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest solution is to undefine the function (navigate in the disassembly to the beginning of the function and press <kbd>U</kbd>) and then redefine the function (navigate in the disassembly to the beginning of the function and press <kbd>P</kbd>). Note that this will reset any variable names you had already set, though.